# NSDictionary and UITableView subtitle

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsdictionary, subtitle

I am trying to make a phone book like application in Objective-C. I use NSDictionary to populate my `UITableViewCell`. I got the title, index, and the sections right but, I can not get the right subtitle for each title. It is always the same subtitle for every title. Here is my code example:

```
@interface TableViewController (){

    NSDictionary *sarkilar;
    NSArray *sarkilarSectionTitles;
    NSArray *sarkilarIndexTitles;
    NSArray *subtitles;
}

@end

@implementation TableViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    sarkilar = @{@"A" : @[@"Alayına İsyan"],
                 @"B" : @[@"Bebek"],
                 @"E" : @[@"Elbet Birgün Buluşacağız"],
                 @"Y" : @[@"Yusuf Yusuf"]};

    subtitles = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Seslendiren: Mustafa Sandal",
                          @"Seslendiren: Akın",
                          @"Seslendiren: Ahmet Özhan",
                          @"Seslendiren: Acil Servis",nil];

sarkilarSectionTitles = [[sarkilar allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
    sarkilarIndexTitles = @[@"A", @"B", @"C", @"D", @"E", @"F", @"G", @"H", @"I", @"J", @"K", @"L", @"M", @"N", @"O", @"P", @"Q", @"R", @"S", @"T", @"U", @"V", @"W", @"X", @"Y", @"Z"];

.
.
.

//and in the cell set up i got this:

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"TableViewCell";
    TableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSString *sectionTitle = [sarkilarSectionTitles objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    NSArray *sectionSarkilar = [sarkilar objectForKey:sectionTitle];
    NSString *sarki = [sectionSarkilar objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = sarki;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [subtitles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

I'd appreciate any help available!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, there are 4 sections: "A", "B", "E", and "Y".
And each section has only 1 row.
So, I assume your `cell.detailTextLabel.text = [subtitles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];` keep getting **"Seslendiren: Mustafa Sandal"** value? 
Try change the line to `cell.detailTextLabel.text = [subtitles objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];` to see if the problem is solved.

**Edit:**

I would change the `sarkilar` dictinary to the following pattern:

```
sarkilar=@{
    @"A": @[@{
        @"title": @"Alayına İsyan",
        @"subtitle": @"Seslendiren: Mustafa Sandal"
    },
    @{
        @"title": @"Title 2",
        @"subtitle": @"Subtitle 2"
    }],
    @"B":.....
    .
    .
    .
    .
};
```

So each object inside `sarkilar` is an array of dictionaries, each dictionary has `title` and `subtitle`.

And then:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"TableViewCell";
    TableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSString *sectionTitle = [sarkilarSectionTitles objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    NSArray *sectionSarkilar = [sarkilar objectForKey:sectionTitle];
    NSDictionary *dict = [sectionSarkilar objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *title = [dict objectForKey:@"title"];
    NSString *subtitle = [dict objectForKey:@"subtitle"];
    cell.textLabel.text = title;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = subtitle;
}
```

Comment: I think this might be the correct solution.;
I also upvoted you so you get closer to being allowed to comment (because usually when you're asking someone to try something you'd do it in a comment).

Comment: Ya, less than 50  reputation cost me the inability to comment.

Comment: I know the feeling :)

Comment: you are right, in the example code i have only 1 row for 1 section. changing the line worked, however if i have multiple rows in a section the same repeating problem remains for the whole section. and the question is changed to what to do if i have multiple rows in a section?

Answer (score 0):

This will not work as you have key from **A to Z** and you are getting sarkilar values by keys (A to Z).

And you are setting **subtitles** by indexPath.row

Its better if you change your structure and get data from single data source.
Like,

```
NSDictionary *mainSource;         
mainSource = @{@"A": @[@{@"title": @"Alayına İsyan", @"subTitle":@"Seslendiren: Mustafa Sandal"}],
                   @"B": @[@{@"title": @"Bebek", @"subTitle":@"Seslendiren: Akın"}],
                   @"E": @[@{@"title": @"Elbet Birgün Buluşacağız", @"subTitle":@"Seslendiren: Ahmet Özhan"}],
                   @"Y": @[@{@"title": @"Yusuf Yusuf", @"subTitle":@"Seslendiren: Acil Servis"}]
                   };
```

And in cellForRowAtIndexPath change the way you get data from source.

```
TableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

NSString *sectionTitle = [sarkilarSectionTitles objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
NSArray *currentContact = [mainSource objectForKey:sectionTitle];
NSString *strTitle = [[currentContact objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"title"]];
NSString *strSubtitle = [[currentContact objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"subTitle"]];

cell.textLabel.text = strTitle;
cell.detailTextLabel.text = strSubtitle;
return cell;
```